# SpringBoot: Separate property files

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've created my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.config.additional-location=C:\Users\user\
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://<db>:<port>/<db>
```

I need to feed Spring with an additional file located on `C:\Users\user\application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```

As you can see I've tried to use `spring.config.additional-location` property into my `application.properties` file.

However, bootstrap tells me that no authentication has been provided.

Comment: Have you looked into spring profiles maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says to use file:C:/Users/user/
the "file:" or "classpath:" part is important.

There are numerous other ways to do this, too.
- profiles (and per profile `application-<profile>.properties`)
- `@Configuration` + `@PropertySource`
- ...

Comment: I've changed to `spring.config.additional-location=file:C:/Users/jcabre/` but it doesn't work yet...

Comment: Profiles should work, it'll load your `application.properties` + `application-<profile>.properties`  that's almost what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use another file name by specifying a spring.config.name environment property. You can also refer to an explicit location by using the spring.config.location environment property (which is a comma-separated list of directory locations or file paths). The following example shows how to specify a different file name:

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject
```

Reference URL:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your alternative properties using `@PropertySources` like this:

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"}),
    @PropertySource(value = {"file:${conf-dir}}/application-override.properties" },ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public class AppConfig {
...
```

The properties in the bottom `PropertySource` will override properties from first one, if the file exists.